# How to add popup after page reload using onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
  function sync_data() {
localStorage.setItem("syncDataClicked", true);
location.reload();
}

window.onload = function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem("syncDataClicked") === "true") {
        localStorage.removeItem("syncDataClicked");
        sync_data('show');
    }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="submit" name="submit3" onclick="sync_data()" value="Sync data">
</body>
</html>
```

```
Html: 
<input type="submit" name="submit3" onclick="sync_data()" value="Sync data">

JS:
function sync_data() {
    window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        sync_data('show');
    }, 5000);
    }
    }
```

This js is not working. After onclick and page reload I need to add the pop by function sync_data(). Is there any solution. I have updated with local storage but its showing the popup message

Comment: You should use localStorage to solve this problem

Comment: I would be glad to help. But what content of the popup you want?

Comment: @ADasGH when I click Sync data button after reloading it should provide a pop up message as show

Comment: @ADasGH when i click it will reload after reload pop up should perform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following code:

```js
function sync_data(string) {
  localStorage.setItem("syncDataClicked", string);
  location.reload();
}
try{
if (localStorage.getItem("syncDataClicked")){
  let popup = new Blob([localStorage.getItem("syncDataClicked")],{type: "text/html"});
  let link = document.createElement("a");
  let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(popup);
  link.href = url;
  link.target= "_blank";
  link.click();
  localStorage.removeItem("syncDataClicked");
}
}
catch (e) {console.log("It's the first time"); }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="submit" name="submit3" onclick="sync_data('show')" value="Sync data">
</body>
</html>
```

Hope you find this helpful!

Comment: This is alert box. If it not enough, if you want literal 'pop-up widow', please let me know. I will do it with blob.

Comment: yes I need pop-up window

Comment: @Ajay please see modified code. Also please remember that many modern browsers have pop-up blockers.

Comment: Yes I have unblocked.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your  window.onload function is already inside the sync_data function. So window.onload  will not be triggered because the page is already loaded when the button is clicked. So your  window.onload function should excute before excute the  sync_data function. So inside the sync_data function you should include flag. According to that flag window.onload function will triggered. you can use localStorage to store a flag. This is my suggest code. I am not sure is it work or not. I was add custom pop up alert to code.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sync Data</title>
    <script>
        function sync_data() {           
            localStorage.setItem("syncDataClicked", true);           
            location.reload();
        }

        window.onload = function () {            
            if (localStorage.getItem("syncDataClicked") === "true") {               
                localStorage.removeItem("syncDataClicked");                
                showPopup();
            }
        };

        function showPopup() {           
            alert('Data synced!');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" name="submit3" onclick="sync_data()" value="Sync data">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried but its not showing popup

Comment: I was apply alert box